# How to assert at build time?

Tags: dart, types, assert

Use case: in a `constants.dart` file, define a String constant. Make sure that it is a 16-characters in length.

```dart
const String myConstant = 'My_16_characters';
```

Unfortunately, I cannot do `assert(myConstant.length == 16)`, since it would have to be in main() function, which is never executed if importing the file as a library (flutter project).

Would [global_assert](https://github.com/cmc5788/global_assert) be the to-go solution, or is there an alternative not requiring a 3rd-part library ?

I will write a unittest for now, but coming from Typescript, this is the kind of check I'd like to have done at typing assertion level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no platform provided way to just ensure that an assert is run at compile time.

The `global_assert` approach is ingenious, using annotations to force constant expression evaluation and allowing you to put the test almost anywhere. The platform libraries do not have something like that.
If you don't want a package dependency just for that, you can easily write it yourself as:

```dart
class Assert {
  const Assert(bool test, [Object? message]) : assert(test, message);
}
```

Then it's just:

```dart
@Assert(myConstant.length == 16)
const String myConstant = "My_16_characters";
```

There are limits to which expressions can be evaluated at compile-time, but string length and `==` on integers is allowed.

(Sadly, it does not seem like the analyzer evaluates the `@Assert` annotation, at least based on trying it on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/), so you only get the error when calling a compiler.)

Comment: Indeed, I wish the error could be reported directly in the text editor :)

Thanks for the great answer.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from the answer from @lrn ... I found that you can also get your text editor to show the error, with this method:

```
class CompileTimeAssert {
  const CompileTimeAssert({required bool assertion, Object? failedMessage}) : assert(assertion, failedMessage);
}

// This Shows a red line in your IDE when the assertion is false, AND when compiling
const _ = CompileTimeAssert(assertion: false, failedMessage: 'Something went wrong');

// This only tells you there's an error when compiling
@CompileTimeAssert(assertion: false, failedMessage: 'Something went wrong')
```

Note: Sometimes your IDE not showing a current failed assertion is a good thing (for example, your environment won't be set - `String.fromEnvironment('foo')` will always be `''` according to your IDE)

Comment: (note: this answer could have been just a comment on the answer from @lrn, if I had enough "reputation". And the "edit"ing the answer was not an option because of "There are too many pending edits on Stack Overflow")